# take union of results in mongoid

Tags: mongoid

I have two mongoid documents `Class1` and `Class2`,both have `subject` field
Now I can get result from individual classes group by subject like this

```
@class1_subject = Class1.all.group_by {|s| s.subject }

@class2_subject = Class2.all.group_by {|s| s.subject }
```

now @class1_subject contains =>

```
{
  "algebra" => [
    #<Class1 _id: 51af35f4066104e046000003, name: "root", subject: "algebra">
  ],
  "algebra-II" => [
    #<Class1 _id: 51af3da0066104f448000003, name: "roo2", subject: "algebra-II">
  ]
}
```

and @class2_subject contains =>

```
{
  "algebra" => [
    #<Class2 _id: 51af07d606610423e7000002,.........,subject: "algebra">
  ]
}
```

After union i expecting this result

```
{
  "algebra" => [
    #<Class1 _id: 51af35f4066104e046000003,name: "root", subject: "algebra">,
    #<Class2 _id: 51af07d606610423e7000002,.........,subject: "algebra">
  ],
  "algebra-II" => [
    #<Class1 _id: 51af3da0066104f448000003, name: "roo2", subject: "algebra-II">
   ]
}
```

How can I do this??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be an approximation:

```
@class1_subject.keys.each do |key|
  @class2_subject[key] ||= []
  @class2_subject[key] += @class1_subject[key]
end
```

@class2_subject now has the result